# Wordpress 3+ slow load times on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: performance

Running a test WP 3.0+ on Ubuntu 10.10 (Server & Desktop)
MySQL, PHP 5.3, Apache.

Installs fine and works ok,

I installed a CentOS VM and wordpress is loading way too faster and its very quick as compared to the one on Ubuntu.

I haven't got alot of plugins or anything on this wordpress install

would be grateful for your insight / suggestions on it.

Also, just today I realized that for some reason the WP 3.0.1 on Ubuntu won't show "`an update is available`" whereas on CentOS it was showing and updated fine. Any ideas ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Something tells me this belongs on http://serverfault.com/. It seems to have less to do with WordPress than your server configuration. Voting to close.

Comment: Even two different OSes were named and it's close to a system issue, there's some information that can be given at hand that is wordpress specific. I don't think it's a performance issue on the server actually, at least it must not be.

Comment: @hakre I don't think it's a PERFORMANCE issue either. I think it's a configuration issue with Ubuntu. Which makes either Serverfault or http://askubuntu.com the right place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that wordpress can't check for updates on the one server but can on the other. Wordpress does not output much information if it can't, it's just an request which takes it's time to time-out.

Install the [Disable WordPress Core Update (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-core-update/) and the [Disable WordPress Plugin Updates (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-plugin-updates/) to disable those update checks and see if it helps.

With the [Core Control (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) you can check which transports do work or not. You can even disable updates with that one as well. So it's probably the only one you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

According to the phylosophy of the fine folks at Debian (which Ubuntu inherits the package from), it is security-wise much better to have wordpress installed under root permissions.

As a consequence, it's not possible to use automatic installation of plugins, themes and the auto-update.
(to be more precise, the wordpress package contains a *patched* version of wordpress)

Thus, is common practice for many people to simple download wordpress from the web and install it manually in the webroot.

Comment: My past [question and answers on specifics of Debian/Ubuntu WP package](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/wordpress-package-configuration-in-ubuntu-server).

Comment: Tacone and Rarst - Thank you for your comments and suggestions.
I have installed Wordpress via wordpress.org download and then manually installing it.

I had a plugin ``twitter`` related which I disabled and it seemed to have pick up speed. I installed LAMP on ubuntu via ``sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`` Wordpress directory is being run as ``www-data`` (``chown -R www-data:www-data`` on the blog directory).

Any suggestions, are you experiencing slow times on Ubuntu too?

Comment: @rihatum I hadn't used it extensively, but I experienced no considerable performance issues with WP in Ubuntu Server, running in virtual machine.

Comment: Nope, but I use ubuntu only for local development, I have no experience on Ubuntu in production environments.